# How to delete post comments from the database via SQL statement?

Tags: database, comments

So, I've taken over management of a Wordpress site that hasn't been maintained very well. We currently have approximately 12,000+ spam comments on various posts. The default UI isn't very helpful at only being able to delete or unapprove 25 or so at a time. Is there a way to do this via SQL?

Comment: Do you want to delete all comments or only specific ones (e.g. marked as spam)?

Comment: absolutely all of them, they're all spam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the following commands in your database

```
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta;
DELETE FROM wp_comments;
```

If you changed the db prefix, the name might be `foo_comments` / `foo_commentmeta` or similar.